# How to hide the custom attribute in backoffice based on user roles?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to hide the custom attribute in backoffice based on user roles?
Only user with specific role should be able to edit that attribute from backoffice. For others it should be non editable.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the context configuration and add `principal` configuration like the following:

The following configuration will be applied for all users :

```
<context type="Book" parent="GenericItem" merge-by="type">
  <context component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea>
      <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.common" position="0">
        <editorArea:section name="book.section.entities">
          <editorArea:attribute qualifier="title"/>
        </editorArea:editorArea>
      </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
  </context>
</context>
```

Duplicate this configuration and add the `principal` property to the context, to be customized for specific users and add `readOnly` option to the attribute  :

```
<context type="Book" parent="GenericItem" merge-by="type" principal="SpecificUserRoleGroup">
  <context component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea>
      <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.common" position="0">
        <editorArea:section name="book.section.entities">
          <editorArea:attribute qualifier="title" readonly="true"/>
        </editorArea:editorArea>
      </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
  </context>
</context>
```